# regard Neural Network input format

Tags: neural-network

I have studies Neural Networks and understood how it's work.
generally, all the examples I have seen talking about transforming the values of the inputs to boolean values and to create vector of weights that have the same number of element that the inputs have.

for example if we have this training set:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaspU.png

then, I will have to format the input like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbeQJ.png

the first table is showing how my inputs will be shown, and the last two will show how our weight vectors for the two labels (classes) will be shown.

so, this is simple, but the question is, how can I present Date in neural network?
because if I work like this, the method will create a HUGE vector!!

anyone knows another method for Neural Network to present inputs?
Thanks.

Comment: When you link to a dataset, don't post an image. In this case you could have easily included it in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Representing dates in Neural Network input vectors

This is not a trivial problem. Since neural networks interpret input values as scalar "signal strengths", you should tread carefully when handling continous variables. Ideally you should represent the dates of the year as 365 individual input signals, instead of using just 1 input (eg: the day of the year).

**The reason why**
This is necessary since you don't want to tell the network that February 2nd is a "better date" than January 1st. If you were to use the latter option, the dates would be represented as 33 and 1 respectively. This would imply that February 2nd is a 33 times stronger input signal than January 1st.

**Options**

- 365 input values: one for each day of the year.
- 52 input values: if you may split the dates into weeks and use the week number.
- 12 input values: by categorizing the dates into their respective month.

The gist of it is: try to categorize the input data. Neural networks works a lot better on categorized data ("yes/no" input values) than on continous data.

[See this link for a similar question.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14634/how-to-encode-date-as-input-in-neural-network)